# Удаление большого количества записей

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Таблица на 100млн строк.

Делаю DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ...;

Условию WHERE удовлетворяют 30-40% записей.
Запрос может зависнуть в режиме preparing на сутки или больше. А потом и вовсе завершится ошибкой. Я так понимаю подготавливается транзакция, в рамках которой удаляются все записи удовлетворяющие условию WHERE, либо транзакция откатывается.

Можно ли удалять записи таким образом, чтобы как только находится запись удовлетворяющая условию она бы сразу удалялась и поиск продолжался?

Comment: Удаляйте записи пачками по 1000 - 10000 штук за раз